# What does the android resource qualifier -b stand for?

Tags: android, localization

In one of the basic android tutorials I came across the resource/config identifier "-b+" that is not explained. Source can be found here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

There it is stated that to support different locales one can make use of the following format when it comes to naming resource folders:

```xml
<resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country code>]
```

A concrete example for the us locale including language code and country code would be:

```
<project_root>/res/values-b+en+US/
```

My question is what does the -b stand for and how does this relate to the differing format omitting the "-b+" convention and on top makes use of the letter "r" to discern language code and region?

```xml
<project_root>/res/values-en-rUS
```

which can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2

Best regards,
Ben